# Why is $\frac{1}{x^{1/p} (\ln(x)^2+1)}$ in $L^1$ but not in $L^p$ for any $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, lp-spaces

From a practice qualifying exam, the goal is to find a function $f \geq 0$ on $(0,\infty))$ that $f \in L^p(0,\infty)$ iff $p=1$.

One function suggested was:
$$\frac{1}{x^{1/p} (\ln(x)^2+1)}$$

So for $p=1$, we have:

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x (\ln(x)^2+1)} dx$ = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{u^2+1} du = \arctan(u) |_{-\infty}^{\infty} < \infty$

So the function is clearly in $L^1$. Now for $p>1$:

$$\int_0^\infty |\frac{1}{x^{1/p}(\ln(x)^2+1)}|^p dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x (\ln(x)^2+1)^p} dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(u^2+1)^p} du$$

Since I can't solve this last integral explicitly, how do I actually prove it diverges? It's clear that on $[1,\infty)$, the function behaves like $\frac{1}{u^{2p}}$ so it converges there (and by symmetry, behaves the same way on $(\infty,-1]$, so I should be able to prove it diverges on $(0,1)$ and that would be enough

Comment: For $p \geqslant 1$, you have $0 < (u^2+1)^{-p} \leqslant (u^2+1)^{-1}$ for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$, so the integral is finite.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmmmmm that's unfortunate. Neither me nor my analysis professor was able to come up to a solution to this problem

Comment: Point is, however, that you look at different functions, since your function depends on the parameter $p$. If you remove that dependence and look at the same function, $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x((\ln x)^2 + 1)},$$ for every $p$, then you have a solution to the problem. $f\in L^1(0,+\infty)$, but $f\notin L^p(0,+\infty)$ for any $p > 1$.

Comment: The function $$f_p(x) = \frac{1}{x^{1/p}((\ln x)^2+1)}$$ is an example of a function belonging to $L^p(0,+\infty)$, but not to any $L^q(0,+\infty)$ with $q \neq p$. For $q > p$, the singularity at $0$ is not $q$-integrable, and for $q < p$ the function decays too slowly at $+\infty$.

Comment: "One function suggested was ..." That's not one function! You need one fixed function f  (without p's in it!)  that has the desired property.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok I follow what you're saying. But why is $\frac{1}{x((lnx)^2+1)}$ not in $L^p$ for $p>1$? I see it's in $L^1$ but not that it isn't in $L^p$

Comment: The singularity at $0$ isn't $p$-integrable. $\lvert f(x)\rvert^p = \dfrac{1}{x^p((\ln x)^2+1)^p}$, and as $x \to 0$ that grows faster than $x^{-(p-\varepsilon)}$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. Take e.g. $\varepsilon = (p-1)/2$ to see $\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert^p\,dx = +\infty$ for $p > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* an $L^p$ function, as soon as $p>\frac{1}{2}$:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\left(\log(x)^2+1\right)^p} =\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^p}= \sqrt{\pi}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(p)}.$$

However, $\frac{1}{x^{1/p}(\log^2(x)+1)}\not\in L^\color{red}{1}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ for any $p>1$.